# Storing personal details of users in Android Studio using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to store details of user like name, email,age etc using Firebase in Android Studio, but it seems only the email and pasword is getting stored. Here's my code, where have I done mistakes? Only the real time database part of Firebase isn't somehow working here. Also, I couldn't post full code here because of "most of it is code add some more details" error.

```
regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Email,Password etc are variables
            final String Email= email.getText().toString().trim();
            final String Password= password.getText().toString().trim();
            final String FullName= fullName.getText().toString().trim();
            final String Phone= phone.getText().toString().trim();
            final String Gender= gender.getText().toString().trim();
            final String Age= age.getText().toString().trim();


            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)){
                email.setError("Email is required!");
                return;
  
            }

            else{
                loader.setMessage("Registration in process....");
                loader.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                loader.show();

                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email,Password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                    String error =task.getException().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(SelectRegistrationActivity.this,
                                            "Error occurred:" + error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                else{
                                    String currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                    userDatabaseRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserId);
                                    HashMap userInfo=new HashMap();
                                    userInfo.put("Name",fullName);
                                    userInfo.put("Email",email);
                                    userInfo.put("Age",age);
                                    userInfo.put("Gender",gender);
                                    userInfo.put("Phone",phone);
                                    userInfo.put("Type","Patient");

                                    userDatabaseRef.updateChildren(userInfo).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                                Toast.makeText(SelectRegistrationActivity.this, "Details set Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }

                                            else{
                                                Toast.makeText(SelectRegistrationActivity.this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }
                                            finish();
                                            loader.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });

                                }

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Is any of the toast messages displayed?

Comment: All toast messages till the "Error occurred" one work. It seems all code inside the else block after it isn't working

Comment: There are multiple else parts. Which one?

Comment: Code from this else block onwards doesn't seem to be working-            else{
          String currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
          userDatabaseRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserId);
HashMap userInfo=new HashMap();
 userInfo.put("Name",fullName);
       userInfo.put("Email",email);

Comment: This means that `Toast.makeText(SelectRegistrationActivity.this,
                                            "Error occurred:" + error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` is displayed, right? What's the error message that you get?

Comment: It displays error message only when email isn't of correct form or if password length is less than 6. Otherwise it doesn't show anything except "Registration in progress" message but nothing gets stored.